# Error while start rails console libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to setup a rails project, after successfully bundle install when I try to run a rails c it gives me following error.

```
`require': libIlmImf.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/lib/RMagick2.so (LoadError)
```

I have installed "rmagick" but still gives me same error.
I have also installed "openexr" as suggested in one of the SO post but didn't work for me.

Any suggestions about how to fix this?

Comment: try running `bundle update rmagick`

Comment: Probably you ran `bundle install` on other ruby version but `rails c` on 2.3.0 version.

Comment: @maxd let me check.

Comment: @maxd no this is not the case I am using same ruby :(

Comment: @TonyVincent I have run that command but still have same error.

Comment: I have figure out the issue, thanks for your help!

Comment: @power I'm running into the same issue. Installed `rmagick` and `openexr` successfully. `bundle install` completed. I actually see the file `RMagick2.so` in the printed path. Can you share how you fixed the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, the issue is the package is missing which contain libIlmImf.so.6, I have googled for so long and found [package link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libopenexr6/filelist)
Pakage: libopenexr6 which contain libIlmImf.so.6

I have then installed that package `sudo apt-get install libopenexr6` so that it solve the problem.

Hope this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Installed `rmagick` and `openexr` successfully. `bundle install` completed. I actually saw the file `RMagick2.so` in the printed path. It turned out that it's a broken ImagicMagic after the system is upgraded. The way I fixed the issue is by reinstalling ImageMagic following the instruction on http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php. I also reinstall rmagic gem afterward, but I'm not sure if that's necessary.